# symfony2 assetic include images in config

Tags: css, symfony, assetic, datatables-1.10

I'm trying to include jquery datatables in a project of mine, so I included datatables in composer.phar to get latest version, then I tried to configure assetic to get css and js files:

this is a partial configuration for datatables:

```
assetic:
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        yui_css:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor.jar"
        yui_js:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor.jar"
        lessphp:
            file: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lessc.inc.php
            apply_to: "\.less$"
    assets:
        datatables_css:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/datatables/datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/datatables/datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css
            filters:
                - cssrewrite
                - ?yui_css
            output: css/datatables.css
         datatables_js:
            inputs:
                 - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/datatables/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js
             filters:
                 - ?yui_js
             output: js/datatables.js
```

MY problem is that datatables images are not copied from vendor to css/images folder.
Maybe it is due to the fact that source file is not a bundle?
I'm using bootstrap too and see that braincrafted bootstrap bundle has a command and a composer handler to purposely copy font files from twbs source in vendor to /web/fonts folder so I was wondering fi a command script is the only way to make such images available in /web/images folder.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `cssurlrewrite` filter with Assetic:

> Since Assetic generates new URLs for your assets, any relative paths
>   inside your CSS files will break. To fix this, make sure to use the
>   cssrewrite filter with your stylesheets tag. This parses your CSS
>   files and corrects the paths internally to reflect the new location.

Link to docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html

Comment: cssurlrewrite is not a standard assetic filter as you can see in your own link; morevoer I already included standard cssrewrite filter but it's no use.
cssurlrewrite is useful but only inside symfony bundles; unfortunately datatables is not.

Comment: In my project, we use bower to download this type of assets and have them in our web folder as an asset. Have you tried that?